# How to set user permissions in net-snmp snmpv3 agent?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have net-snmp SNMPv3 agent.
I have a MIB with read-only and read-write command. I know I can configure SNMPv3 user with read-only or read-write permissions - but, can I have more than that? 
Is there a way to configure for example full write permission and partial write and grant such permission to a user?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “for example"? You didn't give an concrete example above.

Comment: Let us say we have MIB with 3 attribute - A is read-only, B and C are read-write. I want to define a user that has permission to write to B but not to C. is it possible? How?

Comment: Nice that someone that seems does not understand the issue downvote the question after 2 years :-(

Answer (score 0):

There are so called **VACM views** in SNMPv3. So you restrict access to particular branches in the tree. Find out more at: http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Vacm